# Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ

Tags: android, build.gradle

This is the full error-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

I know that there are a lot of solutions to this type of answers but I am an absolute beginner in android studio and I couldnt understand those solutions like the command line interface interacting with gradle and so on...

I was looking for a simple solution to this problem if there is.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: please attach your app `build.gradle`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Recently I was getting this error again....I just go to build->rebuild project and it works everytime for me.

Comment: Every time, When I click on `make the project', It prompts me the same error. Any workaround?

Answer (score 26):

Change all the implementation in your build gradle app
For Example.

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Change It all to latest version(27.1.1) and sync the project.

Comment: Where to make these changes? As in in the build.gradle file should I add these codes ?

Comment: @Dev_123 In the build.gradle (Apps) and change the **version** only. Those code are from my project, so you dont need them. You just need to change the Version and It should be work.

Answer (score 9):

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Modify below line in gradle file.

```
//From 
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//To
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the type of bug that really makes me resent Android Studio.

But anyway, the solution for me was quite simple: Edit the `app.iml` and change the `com.android.support:support-annotations` version. In this case it's easy to find, simply `ctrl+F` and type "27.1.1" (it should be the only hit) and change to your version "26.1.0".

In other words, change it from

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1@jar" level="project" />
```

to

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar" level="project" />
```

Afterwards, rebuild the project. (simply rebuilding it wasn't working for me until i edited the `app.iml`)

Answer (score 1):

its requires just few steps...
1. Go to module.app file. 
2. Change your target sdk version and compile sdk version to latest version ( here it is 27)
3.then change appcompact version to 27.1.1
4. Sync gradle file

Comment: also you have to edit the appcompat version to target the latest version like: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Answer (score 1):

Go to build.gradle(Module:app) file, add `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'` into dependencies, then click 'sync now' again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

instead of

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'`

and change compileSdkVersion **26** to **27**

Answer (score -1):

Your root gradle file should contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google ()
    }
}
```

And the module gradle file should contains libraries like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // necessary for Android API 26
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
}
```

It is just a example of typical simple gradle configuration. Use as needed

Answer (score -1):

#### Use latest stable version of support library

Track here latest versions
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support

As of 28-9-2018 latest version is `28.0.0`.

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```